# Merge SQL tables into One using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to merge several SQL tables from a DB where I don't have direct access, but just the ODBC connection open. All my tables contain the same structure and format. I currently have a code that does pretty much the old school thing but my DB tables are huge with millions of records, hence it's affecting my memory and storage. Any better to run this program and manage memory more efficiently.

**Currently what I do:**

```
import pandas as pd, shutil, glob

table1= pd.read_sql_query("select * from table1")
table1.to_csv(":/file1.csv")

table2= pd.read_sql_query("select * from table2")
table2.to_csv(":/file2.csv")

table3= pd.read_sql_query("select * from table3")
table3.to_csv(":/file3.csv")


#Merging the files

path = r'\\file.*' #Path were your files are located
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
allFiles.sort()
with open('C:\\Desktop\\Outuput_file.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    for i, fname in enumerate(allFiles):
        with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
            if i != 0:
                infile.readline() 
         
            shutil.copyfileobj(infile, outfile)
            print(fname + " has been imported.")
```

Comment: you sure that the query have `table1` in all??

Answer (score 0):

You can use append mode in pandas `to_csv` function.

For example:

```
table1= pd.read_sql_query("select * from table1")
table1.to_csv("C:\\Desktop\\Outuput_file.csv", mode='a')
```

or

```
table2= pd.read_sql_query("select * from table2")
table2.to_csv("C:\\Desktop\\Outuput_file.csv", mode='a', header=False)
```

[referance](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)